# Non SSL to SSL and WWW to NON www at the vhost config

Tags: ssl, apache2

I have a vhost config that works perfectly for SSL.
Then I added this to redirect from non SSL to SSL.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
ServerAdmin mail@example.com

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

This works perfectly too. But now I need a config to redirect www to non www.
So I mean like this:

```
https://www.example.com => https://example.com
http://www.example.com => https://example.com
```

I tried it like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAdmin mail@example.com
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)*(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://%2/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAdmin mail@example.com
SSLEngine on
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)*(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://%2/$1 [R=301,NC,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I tried to check it with curl, I get always the anwser that **http://www.example.com** was redirected to **https://www.example.com**.

Comment: You need `ServerName example.com` and `ServerAlias www.example.com`. Then the same vhost config fits to both. You can add as may ServerAlias as you like.

Comment: In which vhost block did I need this?

Comment: Directly below `<VirtualHost ...>`  as you are having already. HTTP (port 80) and HTTPS often do have own vhost files (i.e. by letsencrypt).

Comment: I have 4 vhosts now, so eveyone need this? Here is my full config https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/CDSPVB4nf6/

Comment: You can do that, but read about [ServerAlias](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html) for simplicity.

Comment: But when I add the `ServerAlias` there must also a redirect from non SSL to SSL for the alias or not?

Comment: Yes, you got it :D

Comment: Last question then I only need too vhost one for port 80 with the alias and one for port 443 with the alias. And the port 80 has the redirect to 443. i don't need the www to non www redirect because of the server alias is that correct?